# AJAX toolkit installation error

Tags: ajax

I have vs2013 express for windows desktop and vs2013 express for web installed on my pc.
I am now studying using AJAX and I tried to download AJAX TOOLKIT from https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/ , but am getting an error in installation **VISUAL STUDIO NOT FOUND**. what could be the reason?

Comment: That you dont have visual studio?

Comment: As I mentioned ,I have it ..Express version not compatible with AJAX ,Is there anything so?